# When I remove the keyword virtual from the below code it works fine otherwise it gives error. What is the significance of word "virtual" here?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

The code below gives a compile-time error but when I remove the keyword **"virtual"** from below it works fine. I know that virtual inheritance is done to avoid multiple copies of base class members, but what is the significance of the keyword **"virtual"** here??

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class A {
    int a;
    A() {
        cout<<"I am A\n";
        a = 1;
    }
    public :
    friend class B;
};
class B : virtual public A {
    int b;
    public :
    B() {
        cout<<"I am B\n";
        b = 2;
    }
};
class C : public B {
    int c;
    public :
    C() {
        cout<<"I am C\n";
        c = 3;
    }
};
int main() 
{ 
    C var;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `gives a compile-time error` Please include the error message.

Comment: C derives from B which virtually derives from A.  A has a private constructor.  C cannot construct an A, since A has a private constructor.  Why won't A be friends with C?

Comment: In this example, there is no good reason for B to derive `virtual`'ly from A, or for `B` to be a `friend` of `A`. If you don't want the `A` constructor to be `public`, at least make it `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 2):

Initializaion of `virtual` base classes follows different logic than regular base classes.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes:

> All virtual base subobjects are initialized before any non-virtual base subobject, so only the most derived class calls the constructors of the virtual bases in its member initializer list:

In your case, the constructor of `C` can be thought of as:

```
C() : A(), B() {
    cout<<"I am C\n";
    c = 3;
}
```

That is a problem since `A()` is declared `private`.

When `A` is a regular base class of `B`, `C()` can be thought of as:

```
C() : B() {  // No A()
    cout<<"I am C\n";
    c = 3;
}
```

That is not a problem given your posted code.